# Windows Server 2012 R12 using up lots of outbound traffic allowance

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I run a website, which is hosted by a company offering cloud hosting (using a VLAN). The site runs on IIS.

I use remote desktop to administer a Windows Server 2012 R12 (Version 6.3 Build 9600) machine - I think it's a virtual machine.

I recently received this notification alert from the host:

> Your VLAN has used over 80% of the free outbound traffic for the
>   month. Once you hit 50GB, you will incur a charge of £0.0200 per
>   Gigabyte on outbound traffic used thereafter.

I'm aware of a website using bandwidth in terms of traffic used up by visitors to the site, but wasn't aware of outbound traffic.

I was told that the outbound traffic allowance, will be the websites that you visit, the emails that you send, the files you download etc. If someone visits your site, that will be inbound traffic.

The thing is, I Remote Connect to the site about once a month, and don't do a lot when I'm there.

The only thing that could use up traffic I thought was that there was a simple tiny web page which I keep open in IE which refreshes every 2 minutes. It has a plain text output made up of 2 lines.

I then looked on the Resource Monitor on the server, and saw I could go to Network, and sort by Send Descending.

I saw all sorts of Addresses listed under an image called "System" using up lots of resources - you can see them all here:

[image]

I have no idea what all those addresses are - they're certainly nothing to do with the running of my site, but they are sending a lot of data to all sorts of addresses.

Is there any way I can find out what is causing this to happen, and any way to stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're a little confused as to what inbound traffic and outbound traffic is in this case.

From the perspective of your web server and the network it's connected to, outbound traffic is the data being sent from your website to the user's web browser every time someone browses your website. Your website pages, images, elements, etc. are sent FROM your website TO the client's web browser. That is outbound traffic FROM the website on the web server TO the client's web browser. Those ip addresses you see in Resource Monitor? Most of those are the ip addresses of web browsers connected to your website.